# Should I refill my DS-160 due to the new changes about Social Media details?

Tags: visas, usa

I am joining an US university this fall for my MS/PhD. For this, I am applying for an F1 Visa.

Also, I am unavailable in the summer because I am away for an internship. So, I filled my DS-160 and scheduled my appointment in July, when I'd return.

Now that the policies have been changed and the DS-160 required more information, should I refill my DS-160? As I understand, there is no downside to re-filling the DS-160 -- the appointment website lets me change the DS160 confirmation number without any hassle at all.

Comment: If there’s no downside, why shouldn’t you?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold for now.

Comment: What needs to be clarified?